# Sufficient conditions to order the solutions to a system of linear equations

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

A pretty elementary question, but does anyone know of sufficient conditions to order the solutions of a system of linear equations? For example, in the system, \begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{32}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}d_1\\d_2\\d_3\end{bmatrix}\end{align*} are there any sufficient conditions on the $a_{ij}$ or $d_i$ such that we may say something like $x>y>z$? All components are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Any reference would be great!

Comment: it will suffice for the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ to be invertible and the coordinates of the vector $A^{-1}d$ to satisfy your inequalities

Comment: Thanks, I agree, though would you know of any results that give conditions on $A^{-1}d$ such that we may recover these type of inequalities? Or maybe some related results?

Comment: There is nothing left  to "recover" left here, the inequalities can be read off $A^{-1}d$. One further simplification is that instead of $A^{-1}$ you can use the classical adjoint (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) - this would allow cubic inequalities (quadratic in $a_{ij}$'s, linear in $d_k$'s - but then you'd need to consider two cases, depending on the sign of $\det A$.

Comment: you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule - which would amount to basically the same thing.

Comment: it's certainly a property of A and d, not A or d.

Comment: Yes, that's right, edited, thanks.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for results like 'if matrix $A$ and vector $d$ satisfy property $X$ or is of type $T$, then $x_1>x_2>\dots$', but perhaps no such result exists at this level of genearlity. In any case, thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: But I have given you a property - a formula (a system of polynomial inequalities in entries of $A$ and $d$) which has to hold true for $x_1>x_2...$. Just as the usual answer to "what is a property for quadratic polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+2bx+c$ to have in order to have no real roots"  is given by $b^2<ac$.

Comment: That's true, maybe what I meant was a property that would be easier to check than checking each component of $A^{-1}d$.